# set paths in init file taking OS into account

Tags: init-file, path

I use the same config file between my windows-linux-mac machines. But I'm having some trouble setting some org folders because of the different definition of paths per OS.

For instance setting my default notes folder for windows:

```el
(cond
  ((string-equal system-type "windows-nt")
    (setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/notes.org"))
```

is giving me `"D:\\my_data/notes.org"`

```el
(setq feeds-file (expand-file-name "notes.org" org-directory ))
```

is giving me `"D:/my_data/notes.org"`

As you can see, none is a working path in windows (or even in linux). How can I define a variable pointing to a path and concatenate any file I need taking Operative System into account?

Answer (score 3):

The setting

```el
(setq feeds-file (expand-file-name "notes.org" org-directory ))
```

is perfect for emacs internal usage. It gives `"D:/my_data/notes.org"` with forward-slashes.

The relevant section of the emacs manual is [G.3 File Names on MS-Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Files.html). It says:

> MS-Windows and MS-DOS normally use a backslash, ‘\’, to separate name units within a file name, instead of the slash used on other systems. Emacs on MS-DOS/MS-Windows permits use of either slash or backslash, and also knows about drive letters in file names.

There is another section on file names in the [elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Names.html):

> On MS-DOS and MS-Windows, these functions (like the function that
>   actually operate on files) accept MS-DOS or MS-Windows file-name syntax,
>   where backslashes separate the components, as well as POSIX syntax; but
>   they always return POSIX syntax.  This enables Lisp programs to specify
>   file names in POSIX syntax and work properly on all systems without
>   change.

If you really need to convert the standard file name into the operating system dependent format you can use [`convert-standard-filename`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-File-Names.html) on file names in standard format.

If you need the windows separator `?\\` instead of `/` you can replace it by

`(subst-char-in-string ?/ ?\\ standard-path)`

where `standard-path` is the file name with `/` as path component separator.

Also be aware of the footnote in the [Section "File Names" of the elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Names.html) that mentions the two functions `cygwin-convert-file-name-from-windows` and `cygwin-convert-file-name-to-windows` for converting file names under cygwin.

> [1] In MS-Windows versions of Emacs compiled for the Cygwin environment, you can use the functions cygwin-convert-file-name-to-windows and cygwin-convert-file-name-from-windows to convert between the two file-name syntaxes.

Comment: Maybe for emacs internals is ok but the init part for windows is not working. The path is not recognized and any operation gives a message: wrong type argument. Will try with convert-standard-filename. Thanks

Comment: @Forge I added the citate of another section of the elisp manual that says that all emacs functions returning paths use slash as path component separator in the return value. I think you have to replace the slash for a backslash yourself if you need the backslash for stuff like `call-process`. I've added an example call of `subst-char-in-string` for that purpose in the answer.